# How can I move onto the next page after submiting the form in reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-router

How can I move onto the next page after submitting the form in reactJs. whenever I submit the form, data is storing in my firebase database but I can't go to the next page after submitting the form. I am using react router but I dont't understand what is the problem with it and also I am getting two warnings in my console.

[image]

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import "./contactForm.css";

function ContactForm() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    tel: "",
  });

  let name, value;
  const getData = (e) => {
    name = e.target.name;
    value = e.target.value;
    setUserData({ ...userData, [name]: value });
  };

  const submitPost = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, email, tel } = userData;
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://reactform-4bea0-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/reactForm.json",
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          name,
          email,
          tel,
        }),
      }
    );

    if (response) {
      setUserData({
        name: "",
        email: "",
        tel: "",
      });
      alert("Your Data has been stored in our Database");
      navigate('/showdata')
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Fill In the form</h1>
      <div>
        <form method="POST" onSubmit={submitPost}>
          <input
            type="name"
            name="name"
            id="name"
            value={userData.name}
            onChange={getData} 
          />
          <input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            id="email"
            value={userData.email}
            onChange={getData} 
          />
          <input
            type="tel"
            name="tel"
            id="tel"
            value={userData.tel}
            onChange={getData}
          />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ContactForm;
```

And here is the code of my App.js file, where I am using Routes

```
import './App.css';
import ContactForm from './component/ContactForm';
import ShowData from './component/ShowData';
import {Routes} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ContactForm/>
      <Routes path="/showdata" element={<ShowData/>} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The warnings are saying there aren't any routes matching where you are navigating. Can you update your question to include the relevant routing code?

Comment: `<Routes>
<Route path="/showdata" element={<ShowData/>}/>
</Routes>`
Define `Route` inside `Routes` tag

Comment: The `Routes` component only handles rendering `Route` components. I don't see a router or properly used routes.

Comment: The content in <ShowData/> is showing down towards <ContactForm/>. I just want to move to the <ShowData/> page by clicking on the button which is in the <ContactForm/>

Comment: Then you need to render a route for it, just as in @MuhammadBilalBangash's comment.

Comment: In your `App.js` replace code that I shared above in the comment with `<Routes path="/showdata" element={<ShowData/>} />` this is the proper way to define route for a page/screen @MuhammadOsama

Answer (score 0):

The `App` component is missing a router and routes to render the `ShowData` component you are trying to navigate to.

- A router, e.g. `BrowserRouter` is what provides a routing context to the app for all `Link`, `Routes`, `Route`, `Navigate` components and all the various RRD React hooks.
- `Routes` is the component that does the route path matching against the URL. All `Route` components need to be rendered into one for route path matching to work.
- `Route` is the component that specifies a `path` to match on and a component to render.

Example Code

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Routes>
          <Routes path="/" element={<ContactForm />} />
          <Route path="/showdata" element={<ShowData />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Note that I also moved the `ContactForm` component into a route on the "home" `"/"` path to fix the first warning about no routes matching "/".